# How might I fix wobble in my studio desk build?

Tags: wood, plywood, tabletop, wood-movement

This is my first major woodworking projects and I'm having a bit of trouble. I have built this custom music studio desk and it keeps wobbling side to side.

It does have a lot of weight on it so it needs to solid. The 'open legs' are 19 inches apart and made from 3/4" inch plywood and the table top is 2 inch thick White Pine as well as the shelves that hold the speakers. There are 6 2x4 beam supports between each leg keeping the 2 sheets of plywood together at 19 inches apart and L brackets on the top and bottom connecting the beam and plywood side together on all sides. The table top is screwed in from the bottom up and that's it.

I chose this design and how to screw it in based off the necessity of needing the space between the legs to be open to host the rackmount equipment. I am pretty limited on what I can do because I need the space to be open as much as possible.

Here is a picture of the desk so far.

Any suggestions will help!

Thanks!   [image: Studio Desk]

[image: back of leg]

Comment: Welcome to WW.SE! Can you post a clearer photo, showing the legs in more detail, as well as how the top attaches to the legs? And/or a sketch showing how things are put together? As it is now, it's hard to see how it's joined, and where there might be room to add supports / bracing.

Comment: @mmathis Thanks for the reply! im currently at work will be home in 45 mins and provide more pics, thanks!

Comment: I've edited the title so it doesn't look like a call for opinions (not on topic here) and cleaned up the formatting slightly to make the main body of the Question easier to read. Two points I wanted to make that you haven't asked about, the "L brackets" you mention are shelf brackets actually and these aren't particularly rigid (they can flex) which is partly where your issues stem from. Second thing is about wood movement which is much more serious, and I'll cover in the next Comment.

Comment: Wood expands and contracts naturally across its width, and in much furniture it needs to be accounted for/allowed for, i.e. you don't want to try to restrict it or stop it. The way you've screwed the top to the plywood legs doesn't really allow for widthways changes in the pine slab (although the flex in the brackets may help you here). How stable the conditions are where the desk is placed is a major factor however, if where you live is pretty consistent as to temp and humidity, or just the studio is fairly well climate controlled, you should have no problems and you dodged a bullet there :-)

Comment: Just wanted to add, your desk looks awesome well done!

Comment: @Graphus Thanks for the edit! And oh wow haha, im not to familiar with any L Brackets or now shelving Brackets for that matter lol. Thanks for the info. And yes the studio luckily is always between 19C and 21C degrees and 47% humidity due to my guitars in the room so i guess i did doge a bullet haha. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Graphus And thanks! i loved how it turned out, took a while tho haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving from side-to-side like this is called "racking".  It involves the piece going out of square.  Essentially the joints you have between the top and the legs do not provide sufficient support against the pieces pivoting relative to each other.

Typically you'd prevent this by having some sort of diagonal bracing.  This could be just a small bracket, or it could be a brace (or even wires) going from corner to corner.  Two typical things that prevent this without being obvious "braces" are aprons and full backs on cabinets.

Given this design I would personally probably add a plywood back to the cabinet on the left with some openings for cabling and some kind of diagonal brace or bracket attaching the right side to the top.

Comment: Great info, thanks! ive added a picture of the back of one "leg" if you would call it that. If i add a plywood piece were the red faded squares are, would that work? I need that space in the middle to be able to add or change cables.

Comment: @MichaeldarolfiOldChannel, yes that should work as long as the two pieces are attached sufficiently well, so they can't shift. Use thin ply or hardboard (1/4" isn't necessary but use it if you can get it) and tack it on with plenty of small nails/brads/panel pins.

Comment: An option for attaching the plywood backing would be using pocket holes. The benefit of them is that you wouldn't have to have any visible fixings on the outside of the leg sections.

Comment: I would also suggest that when you are attaching the plywood, rather than relying on a measurement of the gap and cutting it to the exact length, first cut it to the rough length and check it against the legs. Keep doing small cuts until you get a nice snug fit.

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232 Great thanks for all the help! I have some 3/4 inch plywood left over that i can use. And yes i will take that into consideration when cutting, i do want it to be snug a fit well. Will some screws and wood glue do the job best?

Comment: If you're using 3/4 ply snug inside the box with screws from the outside of the box, then you will get a lot of stiffness from even 12" height (top and bottom). Glue won't hurt, but wouldn't be strictly necessary.

Comment: @MichaeldarolfiOldChannel, just to clarify if needed I was suggesting tacking on material to the back. The other suggestions where you fit panels into the gap require the plywood to be much thicker (3/4" you've already used being ideal), to be cut much more accurately for a snug fit (remembering that the openings may not be exactly square), and, if you're using glue as well as screws the paint needs to be removed from the surface of the ply for a good bond (very tricky sanding operation). Hence my suggestion to just tack on to the back — doesn't need to be cut as accurately, no glue.

Comment: @Graphus I hadn't even considered having the back panel attached on the outside, that is much easier solution (and appropriate). MichaeldarolfiOldChannel I just noticed that you have three cables that are running out of the top of the leg section. Make sure you have enough length in them before you attach the top panel as they will now have to run underneath the panel and back up again. If you don't have enough you could cut a notch or hole out at the top of the panel. Probably easier to do that before you attach it to the leg.

Comment: @Graphus Thanks for the reply everyone! i did what everyone has suggested and it helped for sure but unfortunately still a bit of wobble. I ended up putting 2 1X3 boards making a X across the back which solved the issue 100%. doesnt move a inch anymore! The 3/4 plywood made it stiff but just not enough. I should have taken this into consideration when building the desk. Thanks for all you help!

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Thanks for the reply! Followed what you aid and it helped for sure! Unfortunately it wasn't quite enough stiffness as i do have gear in between the legs and cant allow them to move at all. I ended but using 1X3s to make a X across the back and it solved it indefinitely

Comment: @Stuart Haha good observation, I have enough cable to make it longer and there is no worries there. Thanks!